# SELinux: Creating customized environment to specified user accounts

Tags: linux, selinux

We could map standard linux user into SElinux user accounts. Consider I am having a standard linux user with name "Steve".

Now, I am having 2 questions.

a.) If I map "Steve" into user_u (SElinux account), then he will get execution permission on `$HOME & /tmp` directory. Can I restrict "Steve" from executing applications in $HOME or /tmp. I tried using "neverallow" statement in `policy file (*.te)`, and ended in following error message.

```
Error Message:
 "libsepol.check_assertion_helper: neverallow violated by allow user_t bin_t:file { read getattr open };"
```

How could I override default permissions like user_u is having execution permission in $HOME in SELinux??

b.) I have created a file and changed it's type to "`mytype_t`" using `chcon` command. Then added "`allow user_t mytype_t: file { read write execute };`" into my policy. I have added mytype_t to `/etc/selinux/default/contexts/files/file_contexts & /etc/selinux/default/modules/active/file_context`. "`seinfo -t`" doesn't list mytype_t.

```
  I could successfully create *.pp file. When I tried to install this policy using "semodule -i myPolicy.pp", I have ended with the following error message. It seems, mytype_t is not recognized by SElinux Policy.


Error Message:
libsepol.print_missing_requirements: user_execution_permission's global requirements were not met: type/attribute mytype_t (No such file or directory).
libsemanage.semanage_link_sandbox: Link packages failed (No such file or directory).
semodule:  Failed!
```

Simply I just want to create user "Steve" who can execute aare having standard linux users that are mapped into SElinux user-account. For example "Steve" is a standard linux user-account that can be mapped to any of the following, such as user_u (or) staff_u (or) system_u (or) unconfined_u.ll files with type "mytype_t" in anywhere in system, But should not be able to execute applications with other types.

I am working on debian 6 with policy.24, Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. Perhaps Super User or Information Security Stack Exchange would be a better place to ask.

Comment: We could override default permission set for users by editing "userdomain.if" file in refpolicy source. Trying to find answer for second question!